# to find the application using a particular port

Tags: visual-c++

how we can find the application program if we know port number and ip address in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

IF it's a program you're looking for [**TCPView**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) from Mark Russinovich

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to run the following command and parse the output, then get PID with the specified port number

```
netstat -n -b
```

sample output

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID

TCP    192.168.0.31:1220      192.168.0.27:445       ESTABLISHED     4
[System]

TCP    192.168.1.91:3866      192.168.1.80:3389      ESTABLISHED     61508
[mstsc.exe]

TCP    192.168.0.31:4065      192.168.0.25:80        ESTABLISHED     528
[Smc.exe]

TCP    192.168.0.31:1838      74.125.39.91:80        CLOSE_WAIT      3260
[GoogleQuickSearchBox.exe]

TCP    127.0.0.1:1124         127.0.0.1:4066         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.31:4071      72.233.69.5:80         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.31:4072      72.233.69.5:80         TIME_WAIT       0
```